# Google play store automatically install apps after login to google account

Tags: google-play-store, google-account

Hello my problem is after login in my google account the google play store automatically install google apps like google assistant,google maps , etc and i don't know how to stop it even opening google play store they are not listed while installing

Comment: Depending on your phone some of these apps may be part of the base install.  When you don't have a Google account installed they won't work for you but onece you login to your account they come to life.  If that is the case the best you can do is disable them.  If you let us know the make and model of phone we can confirm.

Comment: And most of the times it isn't installing, just updating, because they're part of the base install, i.e. already installed

Comment: And if you do manage to uninstall them, they will come back.  If you stop automatic updating, it will complain regularly.